# Media Gallery Upload photo incorrect way like glitch

Tags: uploads, post-thumbnails, media, gallery, featured-post

I start having this issue like 3 days ago, I disable all plugins but nothing works.

See the examples:
Original photo:
[image: Original Photo]

after I upload:
[image]

[image: Sometimes this]

[image]

Comment: Looks like your uploads got corrupted, do you get exactly the same glitch when you re-upload? Or a different glitch? Do you have optimisation plugins installed?

Comment: when i reupload is the same sometimes change the glitch
Src: https://prnt.sc/ypqxm8

I Disable all plugins but same